# how to call $scope.$broadcast when use vm=this?

Tags: angularjs, scope

i use 
    var vm = this 
 instead, the use of $scope in the controller now I get this error after compiling the code. plzzz tell me what's  the issue

```
//TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined

vm.$emit("namePublished", {
       "username": response.user
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `$scope`'s methods on `this`. So you need to inject `$scope` and use as usual.

Comment: is this is the ultimate solution for this. or we can do anything else without alter the whole code.

Comment: @rajvansh_viresh, `$scope` is a object, which has it's own properties and functions. You can use it as a simple object. But to use it's functions in the vm, you need to do many works like `vm.$emit = $scope.$emit.bind($scope)`. So it is simple to use `$scope`